# command to check RAM slots in motherboard?

Tags: command-line, ram, system

I have a Samsung NP300e5Z i5 laptop. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in this laptop.  my system RAM is `4GB` and i want to increase it but i am not sure how many memory slots are available in my system. so, how to check

- how many memory slots available?
- how many slots my system is currently using?
- what is maximum RAM size that I can increase to?

any suggestion will appreciated

Comment: For 1 and 2... take the cover off and look at the slots?

Comment: It happened to me once that I ran one of these commands. It told me I had 4 slots. I bought two extra cards, just to open it and find I only had two slots. The other two were blocked. 

Follow @user253751 advice: open it and check it by yourself

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
sudo lshw -class memory
```

It will give you an output like this:

```
 *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 33
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 0
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: AD73I1C1674EV
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 2
          serial: 43D30100
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
```

Here in my system I have 4 memory slots in which currently I am using only one slot. In other slots you can see it shows `empty`.

For maximum supportable memory use:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 16
```

or

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

or

```
 sudo dmidecode | grep -i "Maximum Capacity:" | uniq
```

EDIT: more interactive way to see Slot use small script (suggested by Serg)

```
sudo lshw -class memory | awk '/bank/ {count++} END {print "You have " count " slots for RAM"}'
```

Comment: thanks pl_rock !! my system  showing 4 banks and maximum supportable size is 16Gb . it means i can add 4 RAMs of 4Gb ?

Comment: yes, you can do .

Comment: suggesting a small improvement to your answer `sudo lshw -class memory | awk '/bank/ {count++} END {print "You have " count "slots for RAM"}'`

Comment: @pl_rock No, that's not always true. Some motherboards, particularly in laptops, will report memory slots in `lshw` that are supported by the chipset, but which aren't actually present on your computer's motherboard. There's no way to be sure without checking the manufacturer's specs, or looking inside.

Answer (score 26):

Another way to get all the numbers directly;

To get the total number of slots:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -c '^Memory Device$'
```

To get the number of slots used:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -c -Po '^\tPart Number: (?!\[Empty\])'
```

To get the maximum capacity:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -Po '^\tMaximum Capacity: \K.*'
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ % sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -c '^Memory Device$'
4
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ % sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -c -Po '^\tPart Number: (?!\[Empty\])'
1
ubuntu@ubuntu ~ % sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep -Po '^\tMaximum Capacity: \K.*'
32 GB
```

Comment: The second command wasn't useful in my case.  This seems more robust : `dmidecode -t memory | grep -c 'Size: No Module Installed'`

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou exactly!

Answer (score 5):

The number of memory devices in the results of `sudo dmidecode --type 17` is equal to the number of memory slots, so the command to print the number of RAM slots is:

```
sudo dmidecode --type 17 | grep 'Memory Device' --count
```

The results of this command will be one integer number equal to the number of RAM slots.

The command to show the size of each of the installed RAM sticks is:

```
 sudo dmidecode --type 17 | grep -i size
```

This is a very informative command because it shows the number of empty RAM slots, the number of RAM slots that have RAM sticks installed and the size of each installed RAM stick.

The command to show the maximum RAM capacity (the maximum size that you can increase the RAM to) is:

```
sudo inxi -m | grep capacity
```

This example output shows that the computer has 4 RAM slots (2 empty slots & 2 full slots), and two 4GB RAM sticks (8GB RAM).

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type 17 | grep 'Memory Device' --count
4
$ sudo dmidecode --type 17 | grep -i size
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: No Module Installed
    Size: 4096 MB
    Size: 4096 MB   
$ sudo inxi -m | grep capacity
   Array-1 capacity: 32 GB devices: 4 EC: None
```

`dmidecode` shows the number of slots available for the controller. There are up to 4 DMI types, 2 can be memory arrays, and 2 can be specific slots. 2 are less common. The information in dmidecode/inxi is extremely unreliable when it comes to the array data, but the actual slot data is generally very reliable. If you are looking into buying or upgrading RAM, you should always check the product specifications to make sure that what inxi/dmidecode reports is actually correct. This goes in particular for maximum RAM size and array capacities.<sup>[*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092815/number-of-ram-slots/1092820?noredirect=1#comment1803132_1092820)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### [Quick Answer]

I use the following command to ckeck:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17
```

Out:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0008
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 78111110
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: K4B8G1646B-MYK0   
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0008
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 22800022
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: M471B5273CH0-YK0  
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

You could also use the `sudo dmidecode -t 16` to get the summarized details.